# How to pass a PHP array as parameter from onClick HTML button to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

When I press onClick and call a JavaScript function I want to pass an array. I tried by passing it as parameter but it doesn't work. The array is the data of a row in a datatable, so when I click in Edit button of a specific row I want to take the values of that row only and pass it to JavaScript.

```
<button type="button" id="button_edit" onclick="edit_customer_request()" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="edit_customer">Edit</button>
```

and jQuery :

```
function edit_customer_request() {
    var button_edit = document.getElementById("button_edit");
}
```

Comment: There's no actual jquery in your `edit_customer_request` function

Comment: ..not much you could. you should stringify the array , and passed as  attribute and get it from e.target. However, i suggest keep the data somewhere else and add attribute point to the data instead.

Comment: @AnonyMouze can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assign the onclick in the html as you're doing, you can pass through arguments to the callback function:

```js
function edit_customer_request(element,arr) {
    console.log($(element).prop('type'));
    console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button_edit" onclick="edit_customer_request(this, [1,2,3])" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" name="edit_customer">Edit</button>
```

They even have an example on w3schools documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: how do you add the array itself there `onclick="edit_customer_request(this, [1,2,3])"` instead of 1,2,3 ? I basically need this array `$user` to be passed to JS

Comment: That's outside of the scope of this question here, that seems like a php question. You want to render data you got from php into the HTML. It would probably look something like `<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>`

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. I am not sure how to pass that php array to JS. Kinda lost here :/